# Match a column values to a string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Merged 2 csv files with unique filter as 'NAME' using pandas. Further trying to compare 'STANCE' values to 'bipedal' and print. Summarizing, would like to know the method to compare any column values with a string.

```
s1:
                NAME  LEG_LENGTH       DIET 
0        Hadrosaurus        1.20  herbivore

s2:
                NAME  STRIDE_LENGTH       STANCE
3        Hadrosaurus           1.40      bipedal

merged:
                NAME  LEG_LENGTH       DIET  STRIDE_LENGTH       STANCE
0        Hadrosaurus        1.20  herbivore           1.40      bipedal
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

csv1 = 'dataset1.csv'
csv2 = 'dataset2.csv'
g = 9.8

def splits(c1, c2):
    s1 = pd.read_csv(c1)
    s2 = pd.read_csv(c2)

    print '%s\n%s' % (s1,s2)

    merged =  s1.merge(s2, on="NAME", how = "outer")  # Mergin two files on column NAME
    print (merged)
    return

splits(csv1, csv2)
```

Answer (score 0):

hey little Pandas apprentice, try that

```
df.loc[df.STANCE.str.contains('bipedal')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting below error:     if(df.loc[df.STANCE.str.contains('bipedal')]):
NameError: global name 'df' is not defined

Comment: dude df is the name of your dataframe